# Unable to match strings with jQuery with blank space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to match a string inside another but I am not able to do it:

I want to match a string based on another string that I am typing but I get "false" when I "ask" if "Aston Martin" starts with "Aston ".

EDIT:

Note that the filter is a "as you type", and in this case, I have a blank space in the end of "Aston ".

IMPORTANT NOTE:

Based on @mplungjan answer, I had another issue regarding the blank space at the end of the filter string. Testing it, I was getting the charCode 160, so the solution I used was applying the replace to both strings:

```
.replace(String.fromCharCode(160), ' ')
```

```js
var value = $("#brand").text();
var brand = $("#filter").val();

alert(brand.substr(0, value.length).toUpperCase() == value.toUpperCase());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="brand">Aston Martin</div>
<input id="filter" value="Aston ">
```

Comment: Add all relevant code in the OP for demo use snippet

Comment: Hi, I am unable to insert fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/va5zmd4d/

Comment: How did you insert the snippet?

Comment: You cannot insert a jsFiddle link unless you add code HERE as the alert tells you. So instead hit the `<>` and create a snippet here as I just did for you

Comment: To find "Aston " in the string "Aston Martin" use indexOf instead of substr - `alert(value.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) !=-1);` - at least according to the way you named your variables

Comment: You confused your variable names. Rename `value` to `brand` and vice versa.

Comment: Corrected your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/5q0L8eLL/ . Your `value` variable was pointing to `brand` and your `brand` to `filter`.

Comment: @mplungjan Hi thanks but the string as to start with, and I have to be able to match the string with a blank space.

Comment: @tobiv hi, thank you for the correction

Comment: If indexOf is 0 the string starts with the value and a space in the value you compare with counts too

Comment: @mplungjan yes, but if the filter is "ston " it will return true, and it can't because it's not starting with. It's a brand's list filter based in a typing input, and I have to exclude the brands that does not start but "Aston".

Comment: Please re-read my comment and then look at my answer. One of us does not understand the other

Comment: Have you looked at jQuery Autocomplete? https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using indexOf == 0 will show the string beginning with the brand INCLUDING the space in the value!

```js
var brand = $("#brand").text();
var value = $("#filter").val();

console.log(">"+brand+"<",">"+value+"<",brand.toUpperCase().indexOf(value.toUpperCase())==0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="brand">Aston Martin</div>
<input id="filter" value="Aston ">
```

Onkeyup:

```js
$("#filter").on("keyup", function() {
  var brand = $("#brand").text();
  brand = brand?brand.toUpperCase():"";
  var value = $("#filter").val();
  value = value?value.toUpperCase():"";
  if (brand && value) {
    console.log(brand, value,brand.indexOf(value) == 0); // same as regex /^word /
  }
  else {
    console.log("Something is empty");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="brand">Aston Martin</div>
<input id="filter" value="Aston ">
```

Comment: I think I found one of the problems, I get the  ASCII character 160 at the end, so I get always false between "Aston Martin" and "Aston ". I am still trying to find why and how to solve this...

Comment: That would mess things up :)

Comment: I get 160 testing value.charCodeAt(5) so the problem seems to be there so I have to had .replace(String.fromCharCode(160), ' ')

Comment: That would work for this case. You could also replace all non alphabetical to nothing so I could search for BMW and find B.M.W.

Comment: I have checked your answer has correct. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this:

```
x = "Aston Martin";

if (x.match("Aston")) {
     // Code
}
```

**Update1:**

And if you want that your string should starts with specific word and you want to match space at end you can do this:

```
if(x.match(/^Aston /)) {

}
```

Comment: Hi thanks but the string as to start with, and I have to be able to match the string with a blank space

Comment: @Patrick than you can match with blank space as well like `x.match("Aston  ")`

Comment: The problem with your solution is that I get true if I have x.match("ston ") and I can't. It has to start with.

Comment: than you can check starts with like this `if(x.match(/^Aston /))`

Comment: I think I found one of the problems, I get the ASCII character 160 at the end, so I get always false between "Aston Martin" and "Aston ". I am still trying to find why and how to solve this...

Comment: I have to had.replace(String.fromCharCode(160), ' ')

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help that is also correct, but I will check @mplungjan answer because is responded earlier and I will use his solution in my code.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, and dont forget you have a space in the value of the input?

```js
var value = $("#brand").text();
var brand = $("#filter").val();

alert(!!value.toUpperCase().match(brand.toUpperCase()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="brand">Aston Martin</div>
<input id="filter" value="Aston ">
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but the match has to start with the brand and not be inside of.

Answer (score 0):

please use this one :

```
value.toUpperCase().indexOf(brand.toUpperCase())>=0?true:false
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I get false. Please note that the filter includes an empty character in the end, and that's my problem-